# Microsoft .NET Native alternative download link

Tags: .net, .net-native

Recently Microsoft released .NET Native. I tried to download this package from
[the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/vstudio/dotnetnative) but I got the following error on the download page:

> Page Not Found
>
> The content that you requested cannot be found or you do not have permission to view it.
>
> If you believe you have reached this page in error, click the Help link at the top of the page to report the issue and include this ID in your e-mail: 5b618336-7f98-479f-aef2-88a04ac04ba2

Can anybody provide a mirror link or a copy of this package?

Comment: This looks like an off-topic resource request to me.

Comment: That was just a temporary preview.  It has been incorporated into the VS2015 preview.  This won't ship until summer time.